# Error function not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code:

```
<input width="50" type="text" value="" name="application_id" id="text_input">
<a href="#" onclick="addSelect('1', 'Test Name');" title="Click to add this item">Test Name</a>
```

And javascript

```
function addSelect(id, title) {
    document.getElementById('text_input').value = title;
}
```

When I run code, result error is `addSelect is not defined` ? [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/TmLut/) , how to fit it ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TmLut/2/

Comment: @Nemoden same as you work fine for me if I changed it to no wrap(body)

Comment: And please change to `onclick="return addSelect....` and add `return false;` to the end of your function http://jsfiddle.net/CcdNf/1/ - I also changed to plain JS from mootools

Answer (score 5):

Your script has been defined to run `onLoad`, which means your function is not available in the global scope like you expect. It will be defined in a local scope of some `onLoad` method (whichever jsFiddle uses). With this setting, I think jsFiddle puts your code into this **or something similar** to:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Your code
};
```

(which is similar to `onDomReady` option)

This is so you don't have to worry about binding the right event and you can just test your script (making sure the page has loaded).

When you try to call the function, which you expect to be in the global scope, it won't work. Just change the setting on the left to `no wrap (head)` (or `no wrap (body)`)

http://jsfiddle.net/TmLut/3/

And as mplungjan has pointed out, and I somehow didn't realize at all, when using the `onclick` of the anchor element, you'd probably want to prevent default behavior of the link (even if it's just to go to "#"), and can be achieved in several ways, but one is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="runFunction();return false;">Text</a>
```

Although at the same time, one might argue you shouldn't have inline handlers at all, and would want to be binding the event with Javascript completely. Depending on that case, you have options to prevent the default behavior still. In any case, you can still grab ahold of the `event` object (normalized per browsers...which jQuery does, by the way) and call `event.preventDefault();` in the method.

Comment: When is the `addSelect` name lookup actually performed?

Comment: @Kos On the link click? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here its http://jsfiddle.net/TmLut/4/

I changed `onload` to `head` on the left side select box