# Replacing tags in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some text in a HTML doc like so...

```
<p> MY TEXT </p>
```

And i want to when a certain JS function is fired to replace...

```
<p>
```

With

```
<p><span class="auto-style1">
```

And...

```
</p>
```

With

```
</p></span>
```

So... How do i do it?

(More Advanced...)

I then want to be able to repeat this JS code to replace all the `<p>`'s & `</p>`'s...
So how do i do that?

Comment: If you replace p with `<p> <span>` and /p with `</p></span>` you make invalid html, did you mean `</span></p>` maybe?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: So you're basically asking how to wrap the text inside the paragraph to a span? (But why not just add the class to the paragraph directly?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the question is tagged jQuery...

```
$('p').wrapInner('<span class="auto-style1"></span>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BRyFH/

Comment: Although I would prefer $('p').wrapInner($('<span />').addClass('auto-style1')); <- but that's just the way I like to do things :)

Comment: Why the following example does not work? http://jsfiddle.net/BRyFH/1/ in-which calling the above code from a an ordinary Javascript function.

Comment: @sємsєм You need to set it to not wrap the JS into an onLoad event (second dropdown from the top left): http://jsfiddle.net/BRyFH/3/ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578845/error-function-not-defined-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('p').html(function () {
    return $( '<span/>' ).addClass( 'auto-style1' ).html( $( this ).html() )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with POJS like this.

CSS

```
.auto-style1 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>text1</p>
<div>
    <p>text2</p>
    <div>
        <p>text3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
```

Javascript

```
function wrapContent(element, tagName, wrapperTagName, wrapperProperties) {
    wrapperProperties = wrapperProperties || {};
    var tags = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName),
        tagsLength = tags.length,
        tagsIndex,
        tag,
        child,
        wrappedContent,
        prop;

    for (tagsIndex = tagsLength - 1; tagsIndex >= 0; tagsIndex -= 1) {
        tag = tags[tagsIndex];
        child = tag.firstChild;
        wrappedContent = document.createElement(wrapperTagName);
        for (prop in wrapperProperties) {
            if (wrapperProperties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                wrappedContent[prop] = wrapperProperties[prop];
            }
        }

        while (child) {
            wrappedContent.appendChild(child);
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }

        tag.appendChild(wrappedContent);
    }
}

wrapContent(document.body, "p", "span", {
    "className": "auto-style1"
});
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KZ42h/)</kbd>